# Ruby string manipulation, remove first 3 characters and add them to the end of the string

Tags: ruby

```
mystring = "svn-myapplication" or mystring = "git-myapplication"
```

My desired output:

```
mystring = "myapplications(svn)"
mystring = "myapplication(git)"
```

**Question:** The first 3 characters of the string should be moved to the last with enclosed brackets and the "-" should be removed.

I tried to do something like this:

`mystring.gsub('svn-','')+"(svn)"` but svn might be git, so i want to use the first three characters to be moved to end with "-" removed and brackets enclosed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A regular expression with groups would work well:

`mystring.gsub(/^([a-z]+)-(\w+)/, '\2(\1)')`

Answer (score 5):

You could use e regular expression but the simplest solution is as follows

```
mystring = "svn-myapplication" 
puts "#{mystring[4..-1]}(#{mystring[0..2]})"
```

gives

```
myapplication(svn)
```

Comment: By far the fastest of the solutions.

Comment: @MikeCampbell, why is `mystring[0..2]` much faster than `mystring[0,3]`?

Comment: Maybe it is, I doubt there's much in it and I didn't see your answer tbh!

Answer (score 5):

Lets rock'n'roll :)

```
mystring = "svn-myapplication"
mystring.split('-').rotate.join('(') + ')'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`[]` method of Ruby's String class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) for this:

```
mystring = "svn-myapplication"
mystring = "#{mystring[4..-1]}(#{mystring[0,3]})"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this in irb

```
1.9.3-p362 :001 > mystring = "svn-myapplication"

1.9.3-p362 :002 > mystring.gsub(mystring[0,3]+'-','')+(mystring[0,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to submit this but, at least I can see how to do it better!

```
def test(s = '')
  match = /\w+-/.match(s).to_s
  match = match[0..-2]
  s.gsub!(/\w+-/, '')
  s << "(#{match})"
end # of test
```